# Get data from forms, but run a function depending on what page it's on with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a website with 2 separate forms, and I want to be able to POST the data into two different functions. Let me explain what I mean by that. The first page  is '/'. If a user submits the form from that page, it will send it to the getLoginForm() function, but if they're on the '/control' page, it will send the data to getControlForm(). WHat it currently does is call the getLoginForm() function for both of them. It then immediately error 400s. Heres my code for both of those functions.

```
@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def getLoginForm():
    username=request.form['username']
    pwrd=request.form['password']
#other stuff to do with the username and password. I've made it return the  username just for example purposes.
return username
```

and

```
@app.route('/control',methods=['POST'])
def getControlForm():
    filePath=request.form['filePath']
    #other stuff to do things with the data
    return filePath
```

However, when I submit either form, it always goes through the getLoginForm() function.

My forms are as follows, in the same order as their respective functions.

```
    <form action="." method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="filePath">
    <input type="submit" name="dropboxSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="filePath">
    <input type="submit" name="dropboxSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Would someone mind helping me figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: Where are your views? How are you rendering the pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine the problem is using "." as the form action.  Instead, use the actual path to the page to be posted to.

```
<form action="/control" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="filePath">
    <input type="submit" name="dropboxSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```